# ArcGIS Server Geoprocessing service weirdly changing file path

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I encountered a weird phenomenon on my ArcGIS Server 10.1.

I have a geoprocessing tool that exports a mxd file to an image file on my local directory, say "c://map/dir/export/image.png" It worked well. Then I published it as geoprocessing service on ArcGIS Server 10.1. When I ran it, it still worked but the image file was generated but stored as "export" in "c://map/". This file had no extension.

Additionally, "c://map/dir/export/" was set up as a virtual directory on the IIS so that it can be accessed through web browser whenever updated.

Any idea about a solution?

In my code, I have the following snippet.

```
prodWebServerGCPath = "C://arcgisserver/map/GC/GrasslandCuringVD"
arcpy.AddMessage("* prodWebServerGCPath: " + prodWebServerGCPath)
```

When run as geoprocessing, it strangely printed out as part of GP result:

```
 {
   "type": "esriJobMessageTypeInformative",
   "description": "* prodWebServerGCPath: ..\\grasslandcuringvd"
 }
```

I don't have any data stores set up in ArcGIServer Manager. It happened even if I removed the virtual directory from IIS.

Comment: Can you post the pyscript or a snippet of it. I think I know whats happening but have to see the script to be sure. I also assume you've setup a data store entry? And if you haven't, and are able to : install sp1 for Server. It has some GP publishing fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the gpservice deployment wizard (at 10.1) may have poorly-documented features which resulted in your mashed-up output file and path.

I noticed that your GP result output included a relative path: "..\grasslandcuringvd" which reminded me about the relative paths checkbox. When that feature is combined with the "run GPservice in-process" feature option, the two features essentially equate to: "Run the gpservice locally, and use a local path which appears relative to my deployment path."

So, that combination of locally-run process and relative pathing could have generated a messed up output image path/file.ext combination. (and by 'could' I mean 'probably did')

By now, you have likely upgraded to 10.2 and have redeployed your mxd-to-image gpservice in the new context; if so, I recommend that you edit your Question to update its status.